# CentOS 6.8 で Proxy サーバに ping が通りません / Gateway が設定できません

Tags: centos, virtualbox, windows-10

Windows 10, VirtualBox 5.1.28 に Cents6.8 minimal をインストールしています． 
VirtualBox のネットワーク設定はホストオンリーアダプタで，eth1 を使用しています．
社内のネットワークで使用しており，外部サイトには Proxy を通す必要があります（主な使用目的は yum です）

Proxy は以下のサイトを参考に設定しました（Proxy の認証は不要です）

https://qiita.com/chidakiyo/items/95cbc263f8157cfa5cd7
「CentOS (RHEL Redhat Enterprise Linux) にProxyの設定をする（http,https）」

ところが，Proxy サーバの IP アドレスに ping が通りません．

```
connect: Network is unreachable
```

が出ます．

/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1
は以下の通りです．

```
DEVICE=eth1
TYPE=Ethernet
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=yes
BOOTPROTO=none
IPADDR=192.168.56.101
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
IPV6INIT=no
```

仮説として，Gateway が設定されていない（できない）ためかと思われます．

```
# route
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.56.0    *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
```

以下の 2つの方法を試しましたが，Gateway が設定できません（# route で "*" のままです）

/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1
に

```
GATEWAY=x.x.x.x
```

を追記し

```
# service network restart
```

/etc/sysconfig/network
に

```
GATEWAY=x.x.x.x
```

を追記し

```
# service network restart
```

原因または解決方法ご存知の方はご教示お願いいたします．

Comment: routeコマンドで直接DefaultGatewayを追加するとどうなるでしょうか？ "route add default gw 192.168.0.1" の様に実行します。

Comment: ifcfg-eth0 なのに `DEVICE=eth1` となっていますが、書き間違いでしょうか？

Comment: @cubick `SIOCADDRT: Network is unreachable`となります．

Comment: @metropolis 書き間違いでした．訂正しました．

Comment: eth1は正常にリンクアップしていますか？"ifconfig eth1"でIPアドレスが割り当てられているかと、localhostに対してのpingが通るかも確認してみては。

Comment: ホストオンリーアダプタなので外には出られ無いのではと思います。通信できるのはホストとゲストの間のみです（たぶん）。

Comment: @cubick eth1 はアップしていましたが，いただいた回答のように，ホストオンリーアダプターであるため，ゲートウェイ設定ができなかったようです．NAT の eth0 はアップしていませんでした．

Comment: @take88 ご指摘のとおりでした．

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/94080

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ホストオンリーアダプタはホスト～ゲスト間だけしか通信できません。

外に出たかったら、現在使われてるNICの設定をNATなりブリッジアダプタなりに変えてあげれば良いです。
もしNICの設定を変更したくないのであれば、VMの設定のネットワークから別のNICを追加してそのNICが外に出れるようにしてやれば良いんですが、御社のネットワークの都合もあると思うので、システム管理者などに相談するのが良いかと思います。

特に制約が無いのであれば、ブリッジアダプタに変更するか、ブリッジアダプタのNICを追加してやればつながると思いますよ。

---

ちょっと調べてみたら、ネットワークの共有を使う手もありますね。
http://vogel.at.webry.info/201605/article_5.html

Comment: ありがとうございます．ご指摘のとおりで，NAT 接続の eth0 が ONBOOT=no になっていたのが原因だったようです（ # route でも eth0 が表示されませんでした）．eth0 の ONBOOT=yes に変更で，ゲートウェイ設定が可能になりました．